# user_login não registra último login efetuado

Tags: python, django

Eu tenho uma função de login em Python no framework Django e gostaria de adicionar o log de user_login quando o usuário fizesse o login no sistema. No caso, ele teria que usar essa coluna já registrada no BD e fazer o insert da data do login do usuário, mas não estou tendo sucesso em adicionar a função. Na minha view de login está assim atualmente:

```
class LoginView(views.APIView):
    authentication_classes = (Authentication,)

    def post(self, request):
        try:
            request_user, data = request.get_parameters(request)
            user = request.get_user_by_username(data['username'])
            update_last_login(None, user)            
        except Exception as exc:
            return None
        return response.Response(data=request.user)
```

Comment: Qual é o código de `update_last_login`?

Comment: @mazulo esse `update_last_login` vem doo import de `django.contrib.auth.models`